# Wget for url/.asp?

Tags: wget

I'm trying to download all pdf files under this page with 759 href links that lead to the next level of several pdf links. Following some discussions from this forum I tried the following

```
wget -r -l 3 --accept=pdf --adjust-extension http://www.judicial.gov.tw/constitutionalcourt/p03.asp
```

But it returns with "Removing [url] since it should be rejected.

I'd very much appreciate if I could get some help here. The reason why I added --adjust-extension is because I'm suspecting that url.asp is messing with wget.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
wget -m -r -l 3 --accept=pdf,html,asp --adjust-extension http://www.judicial.gov.tw/constitutionalcourt/p03.asp
```

Comment: I went for wget -m -r -l 3 --accept=pdf,asp --adjust-extension http://www.judicial.gov.tw/constitutionalcourt/p03.asp    , since I'm looking to download .pdfs only. But thanks for the idea!!